# What layer should be logically responsible for handling timeouts to SQL Server?

Tags: sql

I noticed today a couple of errors from my application where it had attempted to insert a record into a table and received a timeout error due to a temporary network delay. The application is coded to recognise this and retry in such cases, which it obediently did. But on the retry it experienced a primary key violation - essentially because the first insert statement had actually completed, but the timeout had occurred transmitting the response back to the client. A primary key violation is considered by the application to be a serious logic error that shouldn't happen and hence it aborted the entire process.

The question to me is what layer should logically be responsible for handling this sort of thing? Ideally I would have thought the SQL client library (in this case ADO.NET 4.0) should do so, but it has no mechanism for auto-retries that I know of. Given it doesn't, it seems like there's a case for low-level wrapper around the SQL client library that can, but I don't see how it could be written without more access to information about when the timeout occurred: e.g. in this sort of example it's possible that

a) the INSERT statement is simply inserting new records using auto-incrementing keys, and hence retrying after a timeout would cause insertion of a duplicate record, OR
b) the primary key violation WAS in fact a logic error, and the initial attempt to insert a a record would have generated the same violation if the timeout hadn't occurred

OTOH I'm sure I could think of examples where whether to retry could only be determined at the application level (especially if it required user confirmation).

I'm actually slightly surprised I'd never seen this particularly sequence of errors before, as it seems quite likely in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently one solution to this particular problem is to use 'SET XACT_ABORT ON'.
This reportedly causes SQL server to roll-back a statement if there's a run-time error on the client. I'm curious why it's not the default behaviour actually.

Comment: `XACT_ABORT` actually has nothing to do with the client encountering a run-time error. It has to do with the statement's executing environment encountering a run-time error. If a transaction encounters a run-time error (on the server), then it will abort and rollback the entire transaction. Your client library, like the one included in .NET, can encounter a run-time error due to a flaw and the transaction may still succeed on SQL Server. `XACT_ABORT` is likely not the default simply to conform with OLE DB common practices; the origin possibly because of some performance enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

The `IDENTITY` property [does not guarantee uniqueness](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx), ever. This means that when you have concurrent `INSERT` statements on a given table, your auto-incrementing value may be duplicated across multiple active transactions.

One way to deal with this is to issue the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` statement before beginning your transaction. This will prevent conflicting inserts, meaning tat no two inserts may be executed in parallel.

The other, more common way, is to simply re-try your transaction or statement, until you do not receive a primary key violation. This should only be done if you are not performing an identity insert and are letting SQL Server take care of the primary key value and it is auto-incrementing.

One other way to handle this in a sort of acceptable way is to use `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` type primary keys. These are almost guaranteed to be unique. You can after a long while, start to receive duplicates; this will require the same logic as the re-try and you lose physical layout optimizations for primary key indexes. This is more of an alternative or note than a recommendation.

All in all, if you want to handle errors and you are using SQL Server 2012, you can simply use the following template to make sure your transaction is appropriately rolled back and that the error moves to the surface:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN TRY
            -- Do stuff here
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
            THROW;
        END CATCH
        
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Also note that this template will not work for nested calls to stored procedures and will roll back the entire chain of procedures if used in that fashion.

**EDIT**

Since you're using ADO .NET, you can disable connection pooling and take care of connection management yourself. If a connection times out while pooling is off, it'll fault on the server side and destroy the transaction, causing a rollback.

Comment: I didn't say I was using IDENTITY though, and my transaction is only inserting a single record at a time. The error wasn't occurring on the server end - it was on the client end while waiting for a response. There's no way for the server to be sure that the client hasn't thrown an exception at the point it finally commits the changes, so I don't see how any sort of server-based solution is going to work. Really the only solution I can see is to check on the client side after the time-out exception whether the record was actually inserted.

Comment: @DylanNicholson It was difficult to determine at exactly what point your process was failing. You mentioned a timeout error and then a retry, but stated that you encountered a primary key violation even though you are using auto-incrementing keys, thus an `IDENTITY` column or some kind of design where your application is taking care of auto-incrementing. In the latter case, I would argue that you should place the auto-incrementing behavior on the server side. With that said, I pointed out many different solutions to combat your problem from several angles.